# Enterprise Architect Python Scripting - Add an element to a Diagram

Tags: python, scripting, enterprise-architect

I am trying to write a python script so that I can add an element to a diagram in Sparx Enterprise Architect.

```
TestDiagEl=TestDiag.DiagramObjects.AddNew("l=10;r=110;t=-20;b=-80","")
TestDiagEl.ElementID=TestEl.ElementID
TestDiagEl.Update
TestDiag.Update
eaRep.ReloadDiagram(TestDiag.DiagramID)
```

It doesn't seem to work, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT
It seems that @geert was right, additionally i didnt add () after Update.

Comment: congratz. Do you have a question as well, or did you just wanted to share your code with us?

Comment: @GeertBellekens Hello :) i forgot to add my question. I hope you can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing code you should know what each line of code does, and why you are writing it.

In this case

```
TestDiagEl=TestDiag.DiagramObjects.AddNew("l=10;r=110;t=-20;b=-80","")
```

Creates a new diagramObject in memory

```
TestDiagEl.ElementID=TestEl.ElementID
```

Sets the elementID of the diagramObject to the elementID of my element

```
TestDiagEl.Update
```

Save the diagramObject to the database

```
TestDiag.Update
```

Save the current diagram in memory to the database

```
eaRep.ReloadDiagram(TestDiag.DiagramID)
```

Get the diagramDetails from the database and show them in the GUI

One problem is the `TestDiag.Update`. Since your diagram in memory doesn't know about the new DiagramObject yet, you are effectively undoing the addition of the new DiagramObject. Remove that line, and all should be OK.

Another problem is the parameter you pass to the `DiagramObjects.AddNew` method. The top and bottom values should be positive as you can see in the provided [documentation](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.2/automation/the_addnew_function.html) So:

```
TestDiagEl=TestDiag.DiagramObjects.AddNew("l=10;r=110;t=20;b=80","")
```

Comment: thank you for your reply; I have tried the code below and i still cant add a new element to a diagam;
TestDiagEl=TestDiag.DiagramObjects.AddNew("l=10;r=110;t=-20;b=-80","")'
'TestDiagEl.ElementID=TestEl.ElementID'
'TestDiagEl.Update'
'eaRep.ReloadDiagram(TestDiag.DiagramID)'

Comment: @SedatYILMAZ I added another issue I found with your code. Maybe that is related?

Comment: it seems that i didnt add " ()" after the Update.  Thank you for your help. Your answer also helped so i mark your answer as the answer

Comment: yet al would like to add that i can use "l=170;r=270;t=-170;b=-230" as a valid parameter in the code.  So negative values also worked for me.

Comment: That's weird. So if you forget the `()` after calling an operation you don't get a syntax error, but it simply doesn't work? I don't use Python myself, but that seems less than ideal.